# Что такое процесс kworker?

Tags: linux, терминология

Объясните пожалуйста простыми словами, для чего нужен процесс kworker в Linux? Какую он выполняет работу? Что означают цифры [kworker/n:n] ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kworker -- подсистема ядра создающая рабочие очереди в основном использующиеся как обработчики аппаратных прерываний. Цифры -- номер ядра процессора и номер потока. Подробнее о нутрянке этой подсистемы можно почитать в официальной документации [Concurrency Managed Workqueue (cmwq)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/workqueue.html?highlight=kworker) и [Reducing OS jitter due to per-cpu kthreads.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-per-CPU-kthreads.html?highlight=kworker)

Comment: Откуда взялось уточнение про  «обработчики аппаратных прерываний»?